# ACL for Joomla 2.5 for backened administrator module

Tags: php, joomla

I need help regarding Joomla ACL.
i am working over Joomla 2.5. I need to give component based user rights.
Please, let me know how it is possible? or is there any free extension available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. If your saying you want to give your administrators access to certain components and modules then yes it is definitely possible. Have a look into User Access Levels - 
http://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms.

Alternatively, you can use a Joomla! extension, here's a good list of them - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control.

It's up to you if you want to use the standard Joomla! ACL or a custom extension, and I can't remember off the top of my head the extent to which the ACL can be customised.